# Edit WiFI parameters in Linux Mint 18 (Cinnamon)

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I just installed Linux Mint 18 with Cinnamon DE. I'm really happy with it, but I have a problem and I cannot solve it.

I'm not able to edit the Wi-Fi parameters after adding them and discover that something has to be changed.

In other words, I cannot find an `Edit` button in the Network Manager interface.

In the following picture, I have to change some parameter of the second Wi-Fi. But it continues to trying to connect with wrong parameters..

[image]

Comment: duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144873/how-to-edit-hotspot-settings-in-linux-mint-14-04

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I'm not trying to edit A hotspot connection while I'm trying to edit the Wi-Fi connections parameters. E.g. if I set a wrong password I cannot undo this and set another one

Answer (score 1):

Click *Known Networks* and activate the misbehaving connection. Click *Forget Network* at the bottom left. Reconnect using the proper settings.

Comment: Thanks! It works for some networks.. But I have one connection (eduroam) that, when I click to connect it it does not ask me any setting anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nmtui` to edit your network from the terminal, Open the terminal then run `nmtui`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I think the problem is different, e.g. with eduroam I cannot set the initial parameters (user, password, etc) so it try to connect without them and it fails.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you can't change the wifi password maybe you encounter the same problem as me.

I don't know why but if I choose to store the password only for me, the password won't change. The solution for me is to ask Linux Mint to store the password for all users.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/701970/where-does-networkmanager-store-wifi-passwords-on-ubuntu-15-10/701980